# Trigger a button on "ENTER" key on Safari Mac

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, get, keyup

I have a search box and I use this following JS to Trigger a button on ENTER key :

**Javascript**

```
var input = document.getElementById("s");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("searchsubmit").click();
}};
```

it works very well on all browser except Safari on Mac.

it is not compatible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended to use event.code instead of event.keyCode
[More documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)

keyCode has been deprecated and might not work properly in all browsers.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("s");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.code === 'Enter') {
      console.log('ENTER');
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="s">
</body>
</html>
```